# I want to filter questions ordered by newest

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, unanswered-questions, newest-questions

Why can't we see unanswered questions ordered by newest? I want to answer this type of question. Is that possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest

Comment: oops thanx buddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion comes from having two *unanswered* buttons to click, do not click the tabbed one, click the button above, then sort by newest:

[image]